# Which method for these sorts of marks on this sort of of light oak or pine wood door?

Tags: repair, wood, wood-filler, scratches

Which method for these sorts of marks on this sort of of light oak or pine wood door?

[image]
[image]

I have read about rubbing walnuts and web stores have all sorts of different touch up pens and fillers. But not sure what to get. I think the walnut and oils will not really fill the hole, but just adjust the shade.

I think I want a filler but I also want to match the color. I am not sure whether I need to fake the texture using paint or whether some product will give me convincing match without having to fake the texture.

I kind of like a multi-part set (like [Seisso](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07ZT4RZ6W)) on paper, but it seems overkill for just one door.

What about a combination of a filler and a sandpaper for moving saw dust form the wood itself over the filler?

They look like one should be done with around 3 separate browns, but I am unsure whether a filler + some coloring method is better than "colored fillers".

Comment: Has the door been finished yet with anything, stain, lacquer, wax, etc?

Comment: @Triplefault How am I going to tell this without having the specs available?

Comment: The reason I ask is that if the door is unfinished, a hot iron and fairly-damp white rag on the blemish can swell the crushed fibers back out and after sanding can make the blemish almost or completely invisible. Trick from 20 years in a cabinet shop. I don't know what you mean by "specs", but try to find out if the door is still raw wood. The iron trick may not work on a door that has been finished. And you'll need a Rembrandt to fill/paint those blemishes invisible. Standard fillers will be seen a mile away.

Comment: @Triplefault Well it feels very smooth, almost like laminate. But I think it doesn't have some plastic coating, but maybe it's sanded and waxed. It doesn't feel like it absorbs moisture. There's a slight chance that the wood outer layer is not wood, but some sort of "wood sticker".

Comment: The idea given here looks promising in theory, but not sure how trustworthy such marketing image is: https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81xexUbDRGL._AC_SL1500_.jpg

Comment: The bottom picture in your post did look a little like broken fibers from the knock, but zooming in it is a bit harder to tell. Lacquered surfaces can feel plastic-y yet allow the wood to crush when dinged. Thermofoil or melamine "wood sticker" usually is applied to particleboard or MDF cores which take a lot more dinging to bend in or crush. You may need to take the door to a friendly cabinet shop to identify what it is made of.

Comment: The amazon link looked good. It's the color matching part and possibly the grain touchup that takes the Rembrandt.

Comment: I am still interested if there's some method that allows sanding small bits of wood dust from the door itself and then using that to color the filler. Because that would match exactly with color.

Comment: You'd need a raw door or raw piece of the same wood the door is made from to get the sanded sawdust.

Comment: @Triplefault Well I already figured that one can safely sand the bottom of the door, because it's invisible in use. One may also find wood pieces from store to match the color, rather than attempt to find a filler that matches.

Comment: Based on the pictures on this Finnish company's site the fix seems certainly doable. Just not sure about the tools. https://www.kolhut.com/kolhukorjaukset-lahti/

Comment: Another popular suggestion based on search results was to use plain white wood putty/filler and then paint it. Just wondering what sorts of paints to get then.

Comment: Some source claimed that the walnut trick may be combined with transparent lacquer. The walnut restores the color, the lacquer fills the hole.